# Replacing Values in a Text File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading a text file.

One line from the text file looks like this and comes at the very end of the text file:

```
</DTS:Executable>
```

I am using `replace("</DTS:Executable>","test from me")`

Nothing gets replaced and the text stays as is.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Strings are immutable... `replace` returns a new string

Answer (score 1):

What is the extension of the file ?

Can you try this `sed` command :

`sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the data in list and replacing the last element, like so;

```
with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
lines[-1] = "test from me"
```

Did this work?

Answer (score 0):

If the file content are not to large then straight forward you can do something like this

```
with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.read()

content = content.replace("<old>", "<new>")

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(content)
```